# How to change the admin login page design and magento admin logo in Magento 2.2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I want to change the Magento logo for login page as well as for the internal pages of backend. I also want to change the copyright text of the footer. I am able to do these changes for the frontend, but I want to these changes for admin.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to find those template files by enabling template path hint for backend/admin.

To enable template path hint : `Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Admin > Yes`

After enabling logout and see the logging page and modify those templates accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a module

Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/admin_login.xml
 and add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-login" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
         <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">
                   Vendor_Module::images/logo.svg
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

and then create a folder in web/images with logo.svg file inside.